# Firefox places font baseline at center of line-height (font: Knockout 46 Flyweight)

Tags: css, firefox, font-face

I'm guessing that Firefox is reading this font's height as 0 in all cases, so that its baseline is always at the center of the line-height. This seems to be a problem with this particular font, but rebuilding the WOFF, TTF, and SVG from the source OTF does not solve the problem. Can anyone point to a more specific cause/solution?

[image: LEFT: Mac 10.8.3, Chrome 27.0.1453.110; RIGHT: Mac 10.8.3, Firefox 21.0]
*LEFT: Mac 10.8.3, Chrome 27.0.1453.110; RIGHT: Mac 10.8.3, Firefox 21.0*

#### CSS

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'HTF46';
    src: url(KnockoutHTF46Flyweight.eot),
         url(KnockoutHTF46Flyweight.otf),
         url(KnockoutHTF46Flyweight.woff),
         url(KnockoutHTF46Flyweight.ttf),
         url(KnockoutHTF46Flyweight.svg);
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
div {
    font-size: 30px;
    height: 24px;
    border: 1px solid #09F;
    outline: 1px dashed #F00;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-family: "HTF46";
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

#### HTML

```html
The border of the box is in blue.
<div>This is some text</div>
The outline of the box is in dashed red, and emphasizes the font displacement.
```

I also tried removing all but one of the URLs in the `font-face { src: }` declaration, to test each font file. Firefox displayed OTF, WOFF, TTF, and SVG all the same.

*(Note: The original from which I abstracted this test included `format('truetype')`, etc. for each font file, but `format('svg')` broke the display of that font, so I left them all off the test.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem and it turned out, that my files for the font where somehow corrupted. I uploaded one file here: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator which generates font files in all kinds of formats and replaced the font files. That fixed it for me.

Might also be similar to this question: [@font-face problem, Firefox adds padding, Chrome does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400296/font-face-problem-firefox-adds-padding-chrome-does-not)

Comment: This is an old question now, and I no longer have the files I used to test. However, I'm inclined to believe this was the case. The web font files were created in a free online tool, and corruption of the file (or a corrupted original) is entirely possible.